# How to write a (media) proxy server in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, proxy-server

I was given the task to write a media proxy server in java, tell me where to start and how to implement it, because I have not encountered this before and have no experience.
I have several (openvidu) servers and a proxy server is needed as a load balancer between them.
I would like to know the subtleties that I will encounter when using a large-scale proxy server that processes thousands of requests every day

I read a lot of information on the Internet, but I still didn't understand where to start, I found a project on github -
https://github.com/stefano-lupo/Java-Proxy-Server, but I'm not sure if this is what I need, the code could be outdated.

Comment: Don't. There are already manu out there, don't try to write your own.

Comment: I didn't find anything about manu on the Internet, and writing my own is not my decision, but team leader

Comment: It is just a proxy like any other.